# Updating the form data in different Controller Action in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony5

via EditController I let the user change his item. then I want to handle the update procedure in another Controller (UpdateController). But it does not work! He creates a new Item instead of updating the Item. In UpdateController I used dd (...) I found out that Id and Profile are not being forwarded to UpdateController.
Hopefully you can help me with it.

This is ItemEntity relationship met Profile

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Profile", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $profile;
```

This is ProfileEntity relationship met Items

```
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Items", mappedBy="profile")
     */
    private $items;
```

This is EditController

```
/**
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
 * Class EditController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
final class EditController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/item/edit/{items}", name="edit_item")
     *
     * @param Items $items
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit(Items $items)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CreateTodoFormType::class, $items, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('update_item')]);

        return $this->render('item/edit.html.twig', [
            'todoForm' => $form->createView(),
            'viewData' => $form->getViewData()
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is UpdateController

```
/**
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
 * Class UpdateController
 * @package App\Controller\Item
 */
final class UpdateController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/item/update", name="update_item", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function update(EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CreateTodoFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $item = $form->getData();

            $profile = $em->getRepository(Profile::class)->findProfileById($this->getUser()->getId());

            $item->setProfile($profile);
            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', $translator->trans('The new ToDo is updated.'));

            return $this->redirectToRoute('item');
        }

        return $this->render('item/edit.html.twig', [
            'todoForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you splited this operation to two controllers?

Comment: And it is creates new item in case of this string in your UpdateController - ` $form = $this->createForm(CreateTodoFormType::class);` . Try `dd($request);` in update() method. But anyway, your solution looks strange - why you don't want to handle form in the edit() action?

Comment: Beacause I want to keep my code's clean.

Comment: And how it makes your code cleaner?

Comment: Everyone has their own method and way of writing codes. 
I would be very happy if you can help me with the solution. Not about writing codes.
thanks in advance

Comment: So, as I suggested - did you tried to dump $request in the update() method?)

Comment: Yes I have used dd($request).  
I get this:

-modelData: App\Entity\Items {#3331 ▼
    -id: null
    -profile: null
    -title: "5"
    -description: "Nostrum officiis est et velit voluptatum excepturi."
    -createdAt: null
    -updatedAt: null
  }


It does not pass Id and Profile Relationship

Comment: Of course, you are not passing the entity object, just fields in the form. There's a very good reason why the suggested approach is what it is. You'd have to somehow load the entity again in the `update` action, for example by passing the `id` as a hidden input in the original form or relying on other uniquely identifying field you already have, passing an `id` parameter  to the route so `ParamConverter` can do its magic or just... you know, handle it on the same `edit` method.